# Blazor: Is is safe to increment static field without lock in component's ctor or inside InvokeAsync?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, blazor, blazor-server-side

Assuming following code, is ID guaranteed to be unique per user session?

```
@code {
    static int counter;
    private int id = ++counter;

}
```

additionally, is following threadasafe?

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
{
   await base.InitializedAsync(); // might return continue in non-ui thread
   await InvokeAsync(() => {
     counter++;
   })
}
```

I think the question boils down to whether

1. two or more component's contructors can run at the same time in two concurrent threads in the same user session
2. two or more blocks of code inside InvokeAsync() can run at the same time in two concurrent threads in the same user session

Comment: If you will have multiple threads executing either of these two pieces of code at the same time, then no, this is not threadsafe.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That much I know, but the threads here are created by Blazor. I know blazor uses multiple threads for rendering, I'm just not sure whether they are concurrent in this case

Comment: The code is not "thread safe" regardless of any current implementation of Blazor. You may "get away with it" (likely) currently, but it is not "safe"

Comment: @MisterMagoo: You are right. I have rephrased the question to better express what I'm curious about

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe for client side blazor (wasm) **as of now**. But not safe for serverside blazor because of the reasons you mentioned.